# Relay Modern - How to use fetchQuery without fragmentContainer

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, relayjs, relay

so I am working on relay for react application with server side rendering. I'm trying to use relay to get data from graphql endpoint.

I was kinda following [this](https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-relay-modern-for-building-isomorphic-web-apps-ae049e4e23c1), using `fetchQuery` to get data by making request from compiled graphql by relay-compiler.

e.g.

```
import { graphql, fetchQuery } from 'react-relay'

const query = graphql`
   query SomeQuery($id: ID) {
      author(id: $id) {
         name
         ...SomeFragment_authorData
      }
   }
`

const variables = { "id" : "1f" };

fetchQuery(env, query, variables)
   .then((jsonData) => { console.log(jsonData); })
```

when it finishes running, it gives me some sort of this object:

```
{
  author: {
    __fragment: { ... }
    ...
  }
}
```

Which I assume will be used by children components wrapped with `createFragmentContainer()` to get the real data.

Since I'm not using `createFragmentContainer()`, I'm not sure how to get the data properly, is there any way to transform above response into the real data?
any help would be appreciated!

Note:

At the moment this is what I do to get the data: `env._network.fetch(query(), variables)`. It is working, but it doesn't seem right that I need to dig into private variable, in order to get the `fetch` that I provided to `Network` object.

Comment: In article you linked `fetchQuery` is imported from `relay-runtime` and not `react-relay`. Maybe changing that way you get the data you're expecting in the response.

Comment: `react-relay` is re-exporting `fetchQuery` from `relay-runtime`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a relay directive to your fragment spread: 

`...SomeFragment_authorData @relay(mask: false)`

Comment: can i know why? i dont understand that "@relay(mask: false)"

Answer (score 1):

you can use relay environment and  relay-runtime utils.

```js
import {
  createOperationDescriptor,
  getRequest,
} from 'relay-runtime';


const request = getRequest(query);
const operation = createOperationDescriptor(request, variables);
environment.execute({ operation }).toPromise();
```